# CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to get xml content

Tags: c, soap, curl

I have used

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
```

and

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream)
{
    printf("%*.*s", size * count, size * count, ptr);
}
```

to get the below output but i need to get only body content

```
* About to connect() to 10.10.1.112 port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.1.112... * connected
* Connected to 10.10.1.112 (10.10.1.112) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /iit_mobile/services/application?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.1.112:8081
Accept: */*
Content-type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.test.com/userloginMethod"
Content-Length: 629

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2013 13:22:35 GMT
< 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   338    0   338    0     0     36      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0* Connection #0 to host 10.10.1.112 left intact

* Closing connection #0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><userloginMethodResponse xmlns="http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.test.com"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Code:**

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{

    out_fd = fopen (filename, "w");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, out_fd);

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=\"http://wsdlclass.wsdlcreat.sims.test.com/login\"");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, tmpbuff);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, buffer_size);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, Timeout);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER,errmsg);

    printf("The Server%s:Performing Transaction.....\n",__func__);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    printf("res=after culreasey perform%d\n",res);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    fclose(out_fd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the headers should not be written out with the body data. If your are receiving headers in your `write_data` callback, that probably means you've set either the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option or the `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` option. You could try resetting both of those to be safe:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, 0L);
```

If you do still want to retrieve the headers, but just not in the `write_data` callback, you can set a separate callback for your header data like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, write_header);
```

Where `write_header` is a callback function, much like your `write_data` function.

```
size_t write_header(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream)
{
    printf("HEADER: %*.*s", size * count, size * count, ptr);
    return count*size;
}
```

Note that it's important you return the number of bytes written from these callback functions otherwise curl would treat that as an error.

If this is still not working for you, the only other explanation I can think of is that your server is returning a blank line before the header data, making it seem as if the headers are actually part of the body.

You easily see if that is the case by testing against a known valid url (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`). If it works correctly there, then you know the fault is in your server code and not the client code.

Having looked at your full code, though, all of that extra stuff you're seeing in your output is coming from the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` options (which you've set twice), and `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS` option. Just comment those out and you should get a nice clean response with nothing but the content body.

I should also mention that there's no point in setting `CURLOPT_FILE` unless you're going to be using the *stream* parameter in the `write_data` callback. When you set the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback, it replaces the default output function, so nothing will get written to the `CURLOPT_FILE` stream unless you do so yourself.

Comment: James can you please have look at my edit and tell me whats wrong in it. Thanks

Comment: @Krish I've updated my answer. It looks like your problem is just the logging options you've enabled - `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS`.

Comment: @Krish Has this answered your question, or are you still having problems?

Comment: Also, you can use `CURLOPT_STDERR` to send the curl debug output to a file rather than to the screen.

Comment: return count*size; wish they'd update the documentation of CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION as it's not obvious to someone just getting started with libcurl